# compute power set algorithm analysis

Tags: algorithm

I have two algorithms to compute power set (all subsets) of a set.
For example, `{1, 2, 3}` => power set is `{}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {1,2}, {1,3}, {2,3}, {1,2,3}`

One algorithm is using iterative solution; `i` (outer for loop) runs for the `nums` arrays and `j` runs for all subsets computed so far and keeps adding `ith` number to previously computed subsets.

```
static List<List<Integer>> subsetItr(int[] nums) {
    List<List<Integer>> subsets = new LinkedList<>();
    subsets.add(new LinkedList<>());
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        int size = subsets.size();
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            List<Integer> current = new LinkedList<>(subsets.get(j));
            current.add(nums[i]);
            subsets.add(current);
        }
    }
    return subsets;
}
```

So given this, I'd like to make sure that I am analyzing the running time correctly. Let's say n is the size of `nums` array then the outer for-loop is `O(n)`. Inner for loop grows exponentially doubled the size each i iteration thus the inner loop is `O(2^n)`. The final complexity is `O(n*2^n)`. Is this slower than the below recursive solution which is `O(2^n)`?

```
static List<List<Integer>> subsets(int[] nums) {
    List<Integer> current = new LinkedList<>();
    _subsets(nums, 0, current, ret);
    return ret;
}

static void _subsets(int[] nums, int pos, List<Integer> current) {
    if (pos == nums.length) {
        System.out.println(current);
        return;
    }
    current.add(nums[pos]);
    _subsets(nums, pos + 1, current, ret);
    current.remove(current.size() - 1);
    _subsets(nums, pos + 1, current, ret);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried measuring it?

Comment: I did .. if I actually run the program then iterative solution takes a lot longer but I'd like to make sure that my run time analysis is correct. It seems like my analysis for iterative solution is incorrect though per the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

they are the same, both complexity are O(2^n), because the complexity of your first algorithm is O(1+2+2^2+...+2^(n-1))=O(2^n), you can't just view all the complexity of inner loop as the same, you have to calculate each separately and then add them all as I do, hope this post help you!